# Could you please suggest better design?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Following is the scenario.

I have something called as `Domain` which can have multiple `States` (Statekey-Statevalue pair) in it. **The same StateKey can be present in multiple domains but with different StateValue.**

e.g. StateKey named 'EconomicCapital' may be present in Domains like 'England', 'America' with values 'London', 'Washington' respectively.

Classes corresponding to these are in common library which can be consumed at client or service side as required.

I have a winform application in which I can select a specific domain. In any string, wherever I encounter any StateKey, I want to replace it by its StateValue for the selected domain.

I can think of following designs:

1. Establish composition relationship. Domain can be composed of the States. So when I want a StateValue of any StateKey, I can get the object of the required domain and can extract StateKey from the States collection composed in it.

But there can be large number of instances where StateKey would be used, I do not think this approach is quite good snce it requires finding Domain object from the collection of domains and iterating through its State collection to find particular key.

OR

1. Maintain a static collection which can hold all StateKeys in different domain. When I want particular StateKey I can simply lookup in this collection.

Could you please advice me which approach is more appropriate? Will there be any other approach/design?

(If the logic is implemented at service side; not just one winform application but many such applications can access it.)

Comment: You should choose a better question title. The current one says nothing about your issue.

Comment: @Diego: I agree with you. But my question was so long that I could not form a single line title which can brief what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like

```
Dictionary<domain, Dictionary<statekey, statevalue>()
```

You could then find the key value pairs from the domain, and get the value from that.... Or am I missing something in your question?

Comment: This is something which I need. My question is 'Will it better to have such collection composed in Domain or better to have some static collection?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... are you referring if it's better to load/generate the set of key value pairs each time you access the dictionary ('composed in domain') or to pre-load/precompute your key value pairs and use the same list throughout the app ('static collection')? That would depend on things like: how much data there is, how many times do you access the data, how hard is to compute/load the data? do you have any performance constraints...

Comment: I agree there is not a clear answer to it unless one has clear answers to the points you discussed in your comments. Since the values are going to be unchanged throughout my application life and I need to lookup in collection many many times, static collection is better suited for me. Thanks for your reply and time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a "thought project"/homework?  Domain > State > StateValue relationships have to **do** something to become a class and use design patterns. This appears to be just a set of lookup operations. You may be better of using LINQ or a database.

Comment: Brian: This is not homework or thought project. I am adding a new functionality to the existing code which is written couple of years back by someone else.